# I need to create layout from an image

Tags: android, android-layout

I have the following picture and I want create layout like it, and I need in place of the rectangles to put EditText views. But I can't figure out which is the best way I can achieve this layout, should I make background of the lines or I make relative layout and try align things?

So if someone is experienced with such layouts, please tell how can I do this.

Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: Your layout looks a bit complex, I'd recommend to use **relative layout**, just try to get this layout via the **WYSIWYG** interface and then adopt it manually to what you really want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That layout is relatively simple to make, it will be a lot more work to make it work across the large number of Android devices. For example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<com.luksprog.ds.views.RelativeLayoutExtension xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >  

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/et10"
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:text="X" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/et9"
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@id/et10"
        android:layout_marginBottom="25dp"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/et10"
        android:text="9" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/et8"
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/et10"
        android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/et10"
        android:text="8" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/et7"
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/et9"
        android:text="7" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/et65wrapper"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/et7"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp" >

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/et6"
            android:layout_width="30dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:text="6" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/et5"
            android:layout_width="30dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:text="5" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/et43wrapper"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/et65wrapper"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp" >

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/et4"
            android:layout_width="30dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"

            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:text="4" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/et3"
            android:layout_width="30dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:text="3" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/et21wrapper"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/et43wrapper"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp" >

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/et2"
            android:layout_width="30dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:text="2" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/et1"
            android:layout_width="30dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:text="1" />
    </LinearLayout>

</com.luksprog.ds.views.RelativeLayoutExtension>
```

Where the `RelativeLayoutExtension` is a class extending the `RelativeLayout` class like this:

```
public class RelativeLayoutExtension extends RelativeLayout {

    private LinearLayout mFirstLinear;
    private LinearLayout mSecondLinear;
    private LinearLayout mLastLinear;

    private EditText mUpperEditText;
    private EditText mLowerEditText;
    private Paint mPaint;

    public RelativeLayoutExtension(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        mPaint = new Paint();
        mPaint.setColor(Color.RED);
        mPaint.setStrokeWidth(2.0f);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onFinishInflate() {
        super.onFinishInflate();
        mFirstLinear = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.et21wrapper);
        mSecondLinear = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.et43wrapper);
        mLastLinear = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.et65wrapper);
        mUpperEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et9);
        mLowerEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et8);
    }

    @Override
    protected void dispatchDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.dispatchDraw(canvas);
        final int leftFirst = mFirstLinear.getLeft();
        final int topFirst = mFirstLinear.getTop();
        final int middleFirst = (mFirstLinear.getBottom() - mFirstLinear
                .getTop()) / 2;
        final int lastRight = mLastLinear.getRight();
        canvas.drawLine(leftFirst, topFirst + middleFirst, lastRight, topFirst
                + middleFirst, mPaint);

        final int rightFirst = mFirstLinear.getRight();
        final int bottomFirst = mFirstLinear.getBottom();
        canvas.drawLine(rightFirst, topFirst, rightFirst, bottomFirst, mPaint);

        final int rightSecond = mSecondLinear.getRight();
        canvas.drawLine(rightSecond, topFirst, rightSecond, bottomFirst, mPaint);

        final int leftUpperEdit = mUpperEditText.getLeft();
        final int topUpperEdit = mUpperEditText.getTop();
        final int middleUpperEdit = (mUpperEditText.getBottom() - mUpperEditText
                .getTop()) / 2;
        canvas.drawLine(lastRight, topFirst + middleFirst, leftUpperEdit,
                topUpperEdit + middleUpperEdit, mPaint);

        final int leftLowerEdit = mLowerEditText.getLeft();
        final int topLowerEdit = mLowerEditText.getTop();
        final int middleLowerEdit = (mLowerEditText.getBottom() - mLowerEditText
                .getTop()) / 2;
        canvas.drawLine(lastRight, topFirst + middleFirst, leftLowerEdit, topLowerEdit
                + middleLowerEdit, mPaint);
    }

}
```

The lines aren't quite centered, it was just an example. 
If you plan to use this layout on a single device for which you know its dimensions the layout will work as you only need to calculate the dimensions once outside of the code. If you plan this as a general layout things will get pretty ugly because you'll need to make a lot of calculations to properly position the views and draw the lines so you may want to rethink your approach. Also I hope that you want to use this layout on large screen devices, because cramming six `EditTexts` along with spaces on a portrait smartphone will not work pretty well.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your effort and your great answer, I will work on it.

Comment: I have implemented your solution and it works as promising after some adjustment. For example I used `layout_marginLeft` instead of `paddingLeft` on wrapper layouts, and center their content.

Comment: Actually there is only one problem in the "Graphical layout" of the xml layout in eclipse, where it gives this exception and show gray area:
`java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.example.test.RelativeLayoutExtension.dispatchDraw(RelativeLayoutExtension.java:42)`
Which refers to this line `final int leftFirst = mFirstLinear.getLeft();` and that means that either `onFinishInflate()` function never called or `findViewById(R.id.et21wrapper)` returns null!

So is there a solution for this problem or what?

Thanks a lot again.

Comment: @Elkfrawy As I said, my code was just a raw sample, it needs improvement. If you used my code, probably the `onFinishInflate` isn't called in the graphical editor(I don't use the graphical editor so I don't know much about its behavior). You could try to move those `findViewById` lines from `onFinishInflate` in the constructors of the custom class.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, actually it works now on eclipse Graphical layout eclipse was need only a restart.
Thanks again for your help.

Answer (score 2):

Looking at that image, it looks like you are trying to cram a lot of EditText's into a single screen. That's a pretty unusual layout... unless your application has a very, very specific use case in mind where another layout is inadmissible, I'd advise you to try using one of the more "standard" layouts in Android, as that will likely enhance usability.

However, if you decide that that's really what you need, then I'd take a look at GridLayout, where the rightmost component is expandable and contains a LinearLayout or something like that.

Answer (score 0):

You can create it with standard layouts.
The main layout is a FrameLayout.
The background is a image with some lines (or shapes to display lines).
The active layout is a RelativeLayout to show all rectangles.